# I want to app know in which day and H we are currently and show the view accordingly. - Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to present a specific view depends on which day we are. I'm building an app that shows the food & drinks menu, but I have different menus for each day and times. I want to app know in which day and H we are currently and show the view accordingly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming showing specific view is not back-end driven. In that case, you can maintain unique view ID for each views. Store views visibility info in local db. your schema could be ViewID, Day, Hours. Educate your code in such a way that when day and hours arrived, show that specific view.

Comment: HI GHUFRAN, thanks for your answer. I appreciate it a lot. I'm a beginner iOS developer and I'm trying to learn by tutorial etc during this uncertain time. I would be very happy if you could tell me more: Where I can find a tutorial or an example?  Since the app is for the family business, I don't have many resources for it. Thank you for your time by the way. All the best.

Comment: Hi Nick, you can try this one. its for beginner. https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-sqlite-tutorial/

Comment: Hi Ghufran, thanks for your message. I had a look the tutorial but I do think is for my case. What I need is to show the main menu Monday to Friday and Saturday and Sunday a brunch menu. So I slip the view in two menus and I want to create a statement that check-in wich day and hours of the day we are and show the preselected menu.